# Batch Renaming of Files in Linux

Tags: linux, sed, centos, rename

I have about 1000 files that i need renamed. The current format is:

```
exten-B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981-G6546525.1.wav
```

I would like to remove `exten-` & `-G6546525.1` . The "exten-" part of the file name is the same in all files but the `-G6546525.1` part is different in all files. Is there a script to remove both parts and just leave `B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981.wav` as the file name?

Hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: The best way to do this depends on OS you are using. sed is almost certainly the wrong approach. So tell us the OS and, if it's UNIX, the shell you are using. Update your tags to match.

Comment: Are all of the files in the same folder, or are they in various subfolders? And how "different" is the `-G6546525.1` part? Are they the same except for digit values?

Comment: First, many thanks for the prompt replies.

Comment: I'm using Cent OS, currently in shell but will wish to run cron at a later, all files are in the same directory. Yeah the -G6546525.1 are random. I was hoping that this could be removed by denoting the last "-"?

Comment: You say you're "in shell". Which shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in "exten-*-G*.wav" ; do
    mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/exten-\(.*\)-[^-]*\.wav/\1.wav/')"
done
```

This is designed to work on the designated file formats and might fail in cases of globbing characters, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I agree. The OP was pretty specific about file name format, so I did assume that narrow definition.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just worth mentioning if there's non-obvious caveats. You can get around a lot of the problems just by quoting your shell variable appropriately (i.e. `echo "$f"` instead of `echo $f`) and others by using printf instead of echo.

Comment: Thanks Chaps, I shall give it all a go and let yous know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the parts of the file name you want using bash or ksh:

```
$ x="exten-B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981-G6546525.1.wav"
$ echo "$x"
exten-B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981-G6546525.1.wav

$ y="${x#*-}"
$ echo "$y"
B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981-G6546525.1.wav

$ z="${y%-*}"
$ echo "$z"
B12345678910-C45679891254-D12345645-E4578981
```

To clarify how to use the above to rename files:

```
for x in *
do
    y="${x#*-}"
    mv -- "$x" "${y%-*}.wav"
done
```

Note that other shells may have briefer methods, e.g. `zsh` has some powerful constructs and some shells have a `rename` command.

Comment: frig, i'm overwhelmed by the quick responses but I have not made myself clear; this is an actual file name: exten-03333456781-07548994578-20131130-135035-1385819435.41.wav  . You may gather that this is a recording from freepbx/ asterisk. I have added in B, C, D, E, G originally as a effort to identify each portion of the file name to yous guys. Please excuse me as im not linux literate, shamefully i started my career in the microsoft arena :(#

Comment: @user3052324 you can used Ed's method to construct the file name you wish and use a shell `for` to do the rename.

Comment: @user3052324 Understood, I updated my answer to make the application explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of batch work using PHP and phpSecLib2 running on my linux box.

Using SecLib, run an SSH connection into the Linux box you want to rename the files on, and run an "ls" inside the folder. Then explode the list of files into a PHP array, followed by a for each loop.

Example code as follows (assuming file location on server is in /home/user/files/ and server location is localhost):

```
    <?php

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('localhost');
if (!$ssh->login('SSHUSER', 'SSHPASS')) {
                exit('Login Failed');
}

$filelist = $ssh->exec("cd /home/user/files;ls");

$filearray = explode("\n", $filelist);

foreach ($filearray as $key) {

    $newarray = explode("-", $key);
    $newfile = $newarray[1] . $newarray[2] . $newarray[3] . $newarray[4] . ".wav";
    $newfile = (string)$newfile;
    $oldfile = (string)$key;

    $rename = "cd /home/user/files;mv '" . $oldfile . "' '" . $newfile . "'";
    $rename = (string)$rename;
    $runrename = $ssh->exec($rename);
}
echo "Done!";
?>
```

The above code should work with minimal changes (username/password and folder location changes).

Comment: Alternatively you could write an almost identical script in python using str.split

Comment: This seems to go against conventional wisdom that you should never try to parse the output of `ls` (google it) and if I understand the script correctly it's not quoting file names on the `mv` and so open to various errors with globbing and other characters.

Comment: Fixed - had forgotten to `(string)` the `$key` and update `$key` to `$oldfile` in the `mv` section. As far as parsing `ls` - there's a difference between parsing `ls` and parsing the output of `ls`. I've been doing it via PHP for years now without issues.

Comment: Ed, Mbratch & Xarus you have made my Saturday a whole lot better! Many many thanks to all, its now working. I have implemented Ed's code into my script which works well. Ed Please ping me your paypal; I would like to make a small donation. Aiden